LT3966 buck converter design
I have designed a PCB using the LT3966 to drive multiple LED strings. The buck topology in particular seems puzzling to me. The datasheet only has one buck application circuit and does not delve into many details regarding layout guidelines or feedback voltage regulations in buck mode. There are no application notes.  The only design resources were for the demo boost controller PCB based on the IC. The ADI support and engineering zone is of no help.

There are 4 channels in the IC. Can I use 3 channels in boost topology and 1 in buck?

The layout guideline was not provided in the datasheet. I followed the generic guidelines for boost topologies but for the buck, it seems confusing. I have attached an image. Any explanation on how the circuit functions is appreciated.




The OV, LED string open detection is based on the feedback voltage pin, but in the typical application circuit, it is tied to INTVCC which is the 3V internal regulator output. In the boost topology, the resistor divider is connected to the output LED string which makes sense but here I'm not sure what going on*

I'm aware these questions should be answered by the Analog Devices application engineers but they are not responding to any cases I have raised.

Please provide a hyperlink to the datasheet of the device. Embed it into your post please.

I did add the link but for some reason, I had trouble posting the question itself. I have added the link now.

Since the internal switch is low side, you will be making a low-side buck. The current sense seems to be high side so perhaps you can manage to fool it. Load it up in LTspice and try?

This device regulates current. There is a programmable over voltage function. Because it regulates the current, feedback is provided by the current sense resistors. All in the datasheet. For better results for assistance, you should sign up to the Analog Devices Engineer Zone.


Yes, you can use it with different topologies on each channel. I have used a circuit with three boost and one buck-boost. Even if buck-boost works differently than buck, it should work as all feedback loops for each channel work independently.

Functional Explenation



In step 1, the internal mosfet connects the inductor to ground and a current flows through the LED and the inductor. This causes a voltage drop across the LED and the inductor. Example: For a 5V LED: The LED anode is at Vin 24V and the cathode is at 19V. Therefore, 19V must be dropped across the inductor (Vinductor + Vled = Vin).
In step 2, the mosfet opens and the energy stored in the inductor in the previous step (the 19V dropped across the inductor) can flow through the diode and the LED again.
This setup works differently than other common buck converters because the LED is never connected to GND/0V. This is also the reason why the FB pin cannot be used here because a higher voltage on the LED from the converter results in a lower voltage drop across the LED, which is exactly the opposite of normal operation in boost mode.
As far as I can see, the functionality provided by the FB pin to detect open LEDs cannot be used here.

For Question 3 i am on the search for an answer too, i created a pcb with 4xx boost converter with this chip and connected the FB (similar to the boost) with a resistor devider to the point where the LED, Inductor and capacitor meet in the circuit layout. cant get it to work, as the voltage wont get regulated correctly (gets above or below 2V), so i guess this was the wrong approach
